# My server program only answers the first request when a second one arrives?

Tags: c, sockets, io, client-server, multiplexing

I am trying to learn about socket programming by writing a server-client prototype program.

Both the server and the client need to be able to handle commands from `stdin`, so I am using the `select` function.

My problem is that the `server` program gets blocked and answers a client request only after the client sends another request.

**server.c**

```
while(1)
{
    if (select(maxfd + 1, &tmpfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    {
        error("Err in select");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < maxfd; i++) 
    {
        if(FD_ISSET(i,&tmpfds)
        {
            if (i == listenfd)
            {
                < add new client to list >
            }
        else if (i == 0)
        {
            < parse server commands >
        }
        else
        {
            /* This is where I think my problem is */
            recv(i, buffer, BUFLEN, 0);
            process(buffer);
            send(i, buffer, BUFLEN, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**client.c**

```
while(1)
{
    if (select(fdmax + 1, &tmpfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    {
        error("Err in select");
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(0,&tmpfds))
    {
        fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, stdin);
        process_request(buffer);
        send(serverfd, buffer, BUFLEN, 0);
    }
    else if (FD_ISSET(serverfd,&tmpfds))
    {
        recv(serverfd, buffer, BUFLEN, 0);
        process_response(buffer); 
    }
}
```

Could you please point me in the right direction ? Am I missing something about how `send` and `recv` behave?

Comment: Remember `recv` blocks indefinitely by default. You can set a timeout with `setsockopt`.

Comment: Also, you need to manage the `fd_set` data within the loop, which you don't... notice, Linux's [`select` tutorial](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut) states that "Since select() modifies its file descriptor sets, if the call is being used in a loop, then the sets must be reinitialized before each call."

Comment: P.S. if using linux, prefer `epoll` over `select`. If using BSD, prefer `kqueue` over `select`. Windows has Overlapping IO and Solaris has `evpoll`... consider using an abstraction library (i.e. `libev`) if your code is expected to run on different systems... Good Luck!

Comment: @Myst I have two fd_set variables, one which is constant(read_fds), and  tmpfds which modifies every time, I forgot to add the line read_fds = tmpfds at the beginning of the while loop, my bad.

Comment: With select() you need to rebuild the FD_SET at the top of the loop, each time.  If you want no blocking, your set should contain ALL your file descriptors.  Never do any read or write operation on a file descriptor unless FD_ISSET says that it is ready, else you run into blocking.  This means you might be in a situation where you have read some data, and you want to write it.. and you can't yet.. so you need to get clever with the order you do things in.. or stash your data in a buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `select` as the correct IO multiplexing facility, you need maintain the `FD_SET` correctly. Since each time `select` returns, the `FD_SET` contains only the fds that are ready for the operation, that means you have to rearm the `FD_SET` before calling `select` each time.

There is another problem in you code, you cannot just add new client in the `FD_SET` in the loop, you need to save it and then rearm them in the beginning.

Also, you don't need to check each FD in the set, since `select` will return the number of fd that are ready for IO.

Try the following changes:

```
int clients[MAX_CLIENTS] = {0};
int I;
int maxfd;
int server_sock = <the listening fd>;
FD_SET readfds;
int ret;
while(1) {
    // Setup SD_SET each time calling select
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfds);
    maxfd = STDIN_FILENO;
    FD_SET(server_sock, &readfds);
    maxfd = max(maxfd, server_sock);
    for (I = 0; I < MAX_CLIENTS; I++) {
        if (clients[I] >= 0) {
            FD_SET(clients[I], &readfds);
            maxfd = max(maxfd, clients[I]);
    }

    if ((ret = select(maxfd+1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,NULL)) == -1) {
        error("Err in select");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < maxfd && ret; i++, ret--) {
        if(FD_ISSET(i, &readfds) {
            if (i == listenfd) {
                 // < add new client to clients array
            }
            else if (i == STDIN_FILENO) { /* keyboard input */
                 //  < parse server commands >
            }
            else {
                  // one of the client is ready
                  int nread = recv(i,buffer,BUFLEN,0);
                  if (nread == 0) {
                       // client is closed, remove I from clients array
                       continue;
                  }
                  process(buffer);
                  send(i,buffer,BUFLEN,0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least, as an improvement over `select`, try something like `epoll` on Linux, which maintains the state for you, so that you don't need to rearm all the fds like `select` does.